# GPS Acquisition Graphs

Tags: discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, sampling, signal-detection

I am trying to generate GPS Acquisition signals using frequency code phase search acquisition.

1. I generated C/A gold codes and digitised at 16.368e6 MHz(sampling frequency)
2. I generated carrier signals using exponential function at sampling frequency
3. I have input data with IF of 4.092e6 and sampling frequency as mentioned above. my input data has 163680 samples
4. I multiplied input data with carrier signals which produces 1023 samples by considering 1023 samples from input data and converted into Frequency dmain using FFT
5. I converted gold codes into frequency domain using FFT
6. I multiplied gold codes with step 4 to get final output with 1023 samples.

Now I want to plot and check for peak. But I don't know how to plot the below graph.

Help Needed in:

1. Understanding the Energy grid like below. The 2 axis are Code Phase and Frequency.
2. Steps/Hints at the RX side to get such grid.
   [image: Picture from textbook]

Comment: what is the language that you are coding?

Comment: I am using MATLAB for coding

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Comment: Hi RohitM, we don't typically deal with coding questions here- you may have better luck in StackOverflow. Good luck!